# Function doesn't stop after "return(False)"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function which is supposed to compare list structures (the values are indifferent). The problem is that I have two lists which are unequal but the function still returns `True` even though it actually goes into the `else` part. I don't understand why and what I did wrong. Here is my code:

```
def islist(p): #is p a list
    return type(p)==type(list())

def ListeIsomorf(a,b):
    if len(a)==len(b):
        for i,j in zip(a,b):
            if islist(i) and islist(j):
                ListeIsomorf(i,j)
            elif islist(i) or islist(j):
                return(False)
        return(True)    

    else:
        print(a,"length from the list isn't equal",b)
        return(False)

#example lists
ListeE = [[],[],[[]]]
ListeD = [[],[],[[]]]
ListeF = [[[],[],[[]]]]
ListeG = [[],[[]],[[]]]
ListeH = [1,[3]]
ListeI = [1,3]

#tests
print(ListeIsomorf(ListeD,ListeE)) # True
print(ListeIsomorf(ListeD,ListeF)) # False
print(ListeIsomorf(ListeD,ListeG)) # False
print(ListeIsomorf(ListeH,ListeI)) # False
```

So the problem only occurs with the third `print(ListeIsomorf(ListeD,ListeG)) # False`. It actually goes into the `else` part and does print the `"length from the list isn't equal"` but it doesn't stop and it doesn't give out the `return(False)`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please fix your indentation (I assume the `else` block is indented)

Comment: +1, please use the [edit] link to fix the indentation.

Comment: Please use `isinstance(p, list)` - it's better on so many terms :)

Comment: It's worth noting that `return` is a statement, not a function, so while they don't hurt, you don't need the brackets.

Comment: @JonClements Or even better, check for the argument being iterable (and not a string if needed), rather than a specific data-type.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that when your function calls itself recursively:

```
            ListeIsomorf(i,j)
```

it ignores the returned value.

Thus the comparisons that take place at the second level of recursion have no effect on what the top level returns.

Changing the above to:

```
            if not ListeIsomorf(i,j):
                return(False)
```

fixes the problem.

Comment: Great thank you! I didnt know that the recursively function does ignore the value, good to know, thank you very much!